# Manual Fourier transform to blur images with Gaussian PSF giving inverted result

Tags: matlab, fft, blur

I am trying to blur an image with Gaussian PSF. Instead of inbuilt convolution in MATLAB, I need to use a manual Fourier transformation to perform the convolution.I use the DFT matrix given as:

```
W = exp(1j*2*pi*[0:n-1]'*[0:n-1]/n)
```

I get the blurred image as the output but inverted.the code is as follows:

```
%%%blur a given input using Gaussian PSF and Fourier transform based
%%%convolution
close all 
clear 
clc
g0 = imread('E:\images\cameraman256.png');%reading the image
figure;imagesc(abs(g0));colormap(gray);axis off;axis equal;title('Image');
g0 = double(g0(:,:,1));
g0 = g0./max(max(g0));
%%%Gaussian PSF generation
%Blur Kernel
ksize = 31;
kernel = zeros(ksize);

%Gaussian Blur
s = 3;
% m = ksize/2;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:ksize);
kernel = (1/(2*pi*s^2))*exp(-((X).^2 + (Y).^2)/(2*s^2));

%Display Kernel
figure, imagesc(kernel)
axis square
title('Blur Kernel')
colormap gray

%Embed kernel in image that is size of original image
[h, w] = size(g0);
kernelimage = zeros(h,w);
kernelimage(1:ksize, 1:ksize) = kernel;
n=size(g0,1);
W = exp(1j*2*pi*[0:n-1]'*[0:n-1]/n);
ft = W*g0*W.';
ft_psf = W*kernelimage*W.';
convol = W*(ft.*ft_psf)*W.';
figure;imagesc(abs(convol));colormap(gray);axis off;axis equal;title('Blurred Image');
```

The DFT matrix implementation has been done according to the source found on the following link:
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6949/how-can-a-2-d-fft-be-constructed-to-an-equivalent-matrix

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By1l0.png)

[Blurred Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWwqw.png)

Comment: The reason that you need to use `abs` is because your kernel is not centered around the origin of `kernelimage`. The origin is in the top-left corner (where the k used to compute `W` is 0). The coordinate system is periodic, so parts of the Gaussian must be visible in all 4 corners of this image. If you do it right, the imaginary component of your result should be negligible (any non-zero value is due to rounding errors).

Comment: The likely cause of the mirroring is that you apply the forward transform twice, rather than an inverse transform the second time.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I constructed another DFT matrix with negative exponential and it works.